# Airflow - Skip future task instance without making changes to dag file

Tags: airflow

- I have a DAG 'abc' scheduled to run every day at 7 AM CST and there is task 'xyz' in that DAG.
- For some reason, I do not want to run one of the tasks 'xyz' for tomorrow's instance.

---

How can I skip that particular task instance?

- I do not want to make any changes to code as I do not have access to Prod code and the task is in Prod environment now.
- Is there any way to do that using command line ?

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: I can't think of any *graceful* solution. You can set up a **trigger** in your Airflow meta-db. As soon as the task `xyz` is about to start and it's `task_instance` entry is made with [`state=RUNNING`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L158) that trigger should immediately update state to [`SUCCESS` or `SKIPPED`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2540d9cd0a446ff74b4e4d50c20d8a82303329fc/airflow/utils/state.py#L36) *(depending on your use-case)*. This might do the trick, but do test it once before putting into prod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark the unwanted tasks as succeeded using the `run` command. The tasks marked as succeeded will not be run anymore.

Assume, there is a DAG with ID `a_dag` and three tasks with IDs `dummy1`, `dummy2`, `dummy3`. We want to skipp the `dummy3` task from the next DAG run.

First, we get the next execution date:

```
$ airflow next_execution a_dag
2020-06-12T21:00:00+00:00
```

Then we mark `dummy3` as succeeded for this execution date:

```
$ airflow run -fAIim a_dag dummy3 '2020-06-12T21:00:00+00:00'
```

To be sure, we can check the task state. For the skipped task it will be `success`:

```
$ airflow task_state a_dag dummy3 '2020-06-12T21:00:00+00:00'
...
success
```

For the rest of the tasks the state will be `None`:

```
$ airflow task_state a_dag dummy1 '2020-06-12T21:00:00+00:00'
...
None
```

Comment: thanks @SergiyKolesnikov for your response. Suppose there is another task named dummy4 and dependency is as follows - dummy1->dummy2->dummy3->dummy4. Per your command, when we mark dummy3 to success, dummy4 starts running immediately. Actually I want to put dummy3 ON HOLD, so that it's downstream tasks (dummy4) won't run. Can you please help me on this ? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AfzAbd you could mark dummy4 (and any other downstream task) as succeeded in the same way as I described.

Comment: Thanks @SergiyKolesnikov. That will help. Is there any way to include downstream tasks  while marking dummy3 task to success. So that all downstream tasks including dummy4 will be in success state. There are many downstream tasks for the task I want to HOLD. Manually running commands individually for all downstream tasks is not a good option, right ?

Comment: @AfzAbd if the answer helped you feel free to accept it. As to the multiple tasks, you could collect their IDs and write a bash loop to to run the command for each of them.