# Skip The Upcoming Airflow DAG Run using Web UI

Tags: ubuntu, airflow-scheduler, airflow

An Airflow DAG that is scheduled to run everyday at 10am using Airflow 1.10 configured to use `CeleryExecutor`.

If it is 9am now and we want to skip today's scheduled 10am run but resume as usual tomorrow, can this be done in Airflow using the Web UI?

Using the Off/On button will not work as doing so will cause the DAG to run immediately when enabling the DAG.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow - Skip future task instance without making changes to dag file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348077/airflow-skip-future-task-instance-without-making-changes-to-dag-file)

Comment: @SergiyKolesnikov Yes it does. Is there also a solution to do this using the web ui?

Comment: I suspect that currently it is impossible to do this in the Web UI. At least, I am not aware of any means to manipulate the state of future DAG runs in the Web UI.